# extracting a subimage in shape of a polygon

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

Consider the following image:

[image: Image of traffic]

This is a frame from a video footage of the traffic.

What I want to do is, to crop out only the oncoming traffic, and analyze it. I want a fast and efficient method with which I can extract, say, a polygon, by providing certain coordinates.

I'm working on OpenCV and Python.

EDIT:
One option I see is treating image as Numpy array and using for loop to extract certain elements, but that won't be efficient and I don't know if its a proper thing to do.

Comment: @Schoolboy sorry, updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest Extracting your region of interest (Any shape you'd want), by using Contours.
Refer to this documentation: [Drawing Contours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#drawcontours)

Your approach should be as follows:

1. Mark points that make up your co-ordinates either on the image itself by attaching a MouseEventListener to the Window.
2. Create a Mask Image by using. (All Zeros)
3. Using these set of Coordinates, use the **cv2.drawContours()** method to draw the shape needed on the Mask Image and fill it with White Colour (255).
4. Peform Bitwise_And Operation with the original Grayscale Image.

Sample Code:

```
#Function
def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags,(cPts,overlayImage,resetImage)):
    if event==cv.CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        cPts[0].append([x,y])
        cv2.circle(overlayImage,(x,y),5,(255),-1)
    elif event==cv.CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP:
        cPts[0]=[]
        print cPts
        overlayImage[:]=resetImage[:]


#Main Program
cvImage=cv2.imread(inputImageFilePath)
grayscaleImage=cv2.cvtColor(cvImage,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
overlayImage=np.copy(grayscaleImage)

cv2.namedWindow('preview')
cPts=[[]]
cv2.setMouseCallback('preview',on_mouse,(cPts,overlayImage,grayscaleImage))
opacity=0.4
while True:
    displayImage=cv2.addWeighted(overlayImage,opacity,grayscaleImage,1-opacity,0)
    cv2.imshow('preview',displayImage)
    keyPressed=cv2.waitKey(5)
    if keyPressed==27:
        break
    elif keyPressed==32:
        print cPts
        cv2.drawContours(overlayImage,np.array(cPts),0,255)
        maskImage=np.zeros_like(grayscaleImage)
        cv2.drawContours(maskImage,np.array(cPts),0,255,-1)
        extractedImage=np.bitwise_and(grayscaleImage,maskImage)
        cv2.imshow('extractedImage',extractedImage)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I  can propose a version of the algorithm:

1. **First discard** the part of image, that you are not interested in. If it a static camera, you can just calculate this region manually. In other case try to use [Line Detection Algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)
2. **Then extract** background with cvThreshold (good example of using [background extraction](http://8a52labs.wordpress.com/tag/thresholding-images-in-opencv/)).
3. **After extraction**, you can find contours and analyze their shape to distinguish objects (cars, people, etc.).

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I propose you do something like:

1. Separate the image into different regions, according to various things mainly lighting.
2. Then for each region, apply a threshold to separate the important areas(traffic), from the unimportant areas(trees etc). (`cv2.threshold`)
3. Using contours, you can distinguish the vehicles from the other stuff.(`cv2.findContours` and more)

If you have a stream of video or something like it, you can use something like Motion Detection too.

Some links you might find useful:

- [Tutorial on Contours](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html)
- [Some things about Hough lines and Hough circles](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm)
- [Thresholds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_%28image_processing%29) and [How they work](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)
- [Question with code on Motion Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3374828/1931274).