# Track motion with OpenCV (cv2 in Python)

Tags: python, opencv

Is there an example of motion tracking with [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces/10425504#10425504)?

The document to cv2 is almost not there (well there is, but...). Especially a cv2 version of the code in Stack Overflow question *[How do I track motion using OpenCV in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374828)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the lk_demo in the `samples/python2` directory in the OpenCV download.

Comment: I am looking for cv2 version, since many function calls are changed and not back compatible. Poor documentation makes it harder.

Comment: In the latest version the python2 folder the example of the tracking is now called lk_track.py. See  [link](https://github.ugent.be/divhaere/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/lk_track.py)

Comment: Thanks wrdeman, I had a look at the lk_track, there is a new module called video ("import video"), which is not there with opencv (version 2.4.4a) installation I have on my mac os x.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example link, as it might help.

http://www.calebmadrigal.com/facial-detection-opencv-python/#comment-19420

Comment: I am looking for openCV version of cv (cv2).