# Syntax error in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I've been attempting to use OpenCV on the Raspberry Pi to get blob detection working.
I know very little about python itself, and so I've been using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374828/how-do-i-track-motion-using-opencv-in-python) to get it working. However, after attempting to run it, I've encountered Syntax Error: invalid syntax
at line 47:

`cv.Circle(color_image, center point, 40, cv.CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 1)`

I'm having issues finding what the error is, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "center point" is not a valid name because of the space.

Comment: Fixed that, still getting the same error message.

Comment: Is the center point an x,y pair?  It would help to see more code.

Comment: The code I'm using is in the link in the original post, the first instance of center_point is 'center_point = reduce(lambda a, b: ((a[0] + b[0]) / 2, (a[1] + b[1]) / 2), points)', right above the line with the error